# jQuery Add object to dynamic parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New to jQuery, having an issue with dynamically changing the selector.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      function addFirst(){
        var fc = document.getElementById("fc").value;
        $("#parent").append("<div id='firstChild" + fc + "'>My boring text.</div><a href='#' onClick='addSecond(\"firstChild" + fc +"\")'>Add Second Child</a>");
        fc = (fc - 1) + 2;
        document.getElementById("fc").value = fc;
    }

    function addSecond(){
      $(***THE PARENT SELECTOR***).append("<div>Some more boring text.</div>");
    }
  </script>


  <body>
    <input type="hidden" id="fc" value="1"
    <div id="parent"></div>
    <a href="#" onClick=" addFirst('#parent');">Add First Child</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need a selector that gets me the direct parent of an object when that parent object has been created dynamically, as indicated by my text "***THE PARENT SELECTOR***".

***EDIT***

My solution to this, in case anyone else comes across this question, was to use .call inside the onClick event.

Located in the string of the **addFirst()** function:

```
<a href='#' onClick='addSecond.call(this,\"firstChild" + fc +"\"); return false;'>
```

Then, changed the **addSecond()** function:

```
$(this.parentNode).prepend("<div>BlahBlah");
```

Comment: did you try `$(this).after()` instead of append()?

Comment: I actually used .prepend().  They all essentially do the same thing, just a matter of where you want to content to go.  I put the activator link inside the div that I wanted the content to go so as to avoid any parent/child confusion.

The part that made the most difference was:

`<<a href='#' onClick='addSecond.call(this,\"#firstChild" + fc + "\"); return false;'></a>`

The `.call` set the parameter for the selector in the function `addSecond()` to be whatever object I specified.  Then, in the function:

`$(this.parentNode).prepend(<div>BlahBlah</div>);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter how the object was created, the selector will work the same.

```
$(this).parent().append("<div>Some more boring text.</div>");
```

As noted, this will not work unless you pass a reference to your object.  You could leverage jQuery more and all of this will be much easier:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("body").on('click', '.addsecond', function() {
          $(this).parent().append("<div>Some more boring text.</div>");
        });

        $("body").on('click', '.addfirst', function() {
          var fc = $('.fc').length + 1;
          $("#parent").append("<div id='firstChild" + fc + "' class='fc'>My boring text.</div><a href='#' class='addsecond'>Add Second Child</a>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <a href="#" onClick=" class="addfirst">Add First Child</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note, that I added a class `addfirst` and `addsecond`.  These are used to add handlers to the links automatically (or more accurately, attach handlers to the body, which trigger when divs with these classes are clicked).  When they are clicked, `this` is passed to the function, allowing you to find that object's parent, etc.

You could clean this code up even further, but I can't guess how you are using it.  I am guessing you want the children added somewhere different than where they are actually ending up.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/2LjYH/

If I were to guess, I would make `#parent` wrap the "Add First Child" link, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="fc" value="1"
<div id="parent">
   <a href="#" onClick=" class="addfirst">Add First Child</a>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XjUzA/

This seems to work more intuitively.  And if you want the second child added directly after the link, you don't want `.parent().append()` at all, you simply want to use `.after()`:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XjUzA/1/

Comment: `this` in the `addSecond()` function isn't a reference to the element clicked.

Comment: Does the onClick argument change?

Comment: @am_not_i_am: I know... which is why I was working on the second part of my answer.

Comment: @Tim:  It would, if you only used that part, but I would suggest attaching handlers in your javascript.  It makes your code cleaner, and jQuery takes care of passing the object references for you.  See my edit.

Comment: @am not i am: You're saying that when "this" is called as a selector in the addSecond() functions, it doesn't have a "this" to call to because it doesn't know where "this" is?

Comment: @TimPlummer: Yes, in your inline `onClick` attribute it will know that `this` is a reference to the element that owns the handler. But in the `addSecond()` function it doesn't, so you'd need to convey that element reference to the function by passing it somehow.

Comment: See jsfiddle examples in answer.

Comment: @am not i am:  :)  My original answer was simply an example of how to call `.parent()`, and a statement that the dynamic nature was irrelevant.  In the context of `onClick=addSecond...`, it was wrong, which is why I was adding the second part.  I actually changed my mind about how I wanted to answer the question.

Comment: @Jeff B, you're absolutely right.  They were popping up in the first "#firstChild" they found or duplicating across all ".firstChilds" found in my production model of this code.  I tried doing "$(this).parent().append(); but it wasn't doing anything.

There was another answer on this Q that was removed, but it ended up working.  The contributor said to change the onClick to onClick="addSecond.call(this,'firstChild') and then $(this.parendNode).append();

Last problem is, it's putting it to the top most level parent and not the local parent.  Any guesses?

Comment: I suspect you want `after()` and not `parent().append()`.  So, with your code, it would be `$(this).after(<yourCodeHere>)`.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/XjUzA/1/

Comment: A parent is a tag which wraps another tag: `<parent><child></child></parent>`.  I think what you are asking for is simply an earlier sibling:  `<sibling1></sibling1> <sibling2></sibling2>`

Comment: Sweet.  Kind of changes my whole script model, but awesome none the less.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `this` keyword refers to the target element you can select the parent using

```
$(this).parent();
```

Comment: `this` in the `addSecond()` function isn't a reference to the element clicked.

Comment: So,

    function addSecond(){
      $(this).parent().append(<div>Blahblahblah</div>);
    }

By bad, no love for code samples in comments.

Comment: @Tim: Put backticks around code in comments.  (The one on the `~` key)